# select query to get all values based on distinct values using linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have n number of services and under each service there will be 2 routes(some times more than 2). Under each route there are n number of stops. I am getting values from db as  a table in below column order
ServiceId, Service Name,serviceLine color,RouteId, Route Name, Stop Id, Stop Name, Latitude, Longitude.

I want to convert it an object list of below format

```html
 public class Service
    {
        public string ServiceId { get; set; }
        public string ServiceName { get; set; }
        public string ServiceLineColor { get; set; }
        public List<RouteData> RouteList { get; set; }
    }
    public class RouteData
    {
        public string RouteId { get; set; }
        public string RouteCode { get; set; }
        public string RouteName { get; set; }
        public List<StopData> stopList { get; set; }
    }
    public class StopData
    {
        public string StopCode { get; set; }
        public string StopName { get; set; }
        public string Latitude { get; set; }
        public string Longitude { get; set; }
        public string StopType { get; set; }
    }
```

Is there any easy way in linq to convert data in to below format? I wanted to avoid looping.. since i am getting nearly 1k records from db. Please help me to solve this issue.

Or is it best to use db calls to format data. i didn't prefer that because if there is 50 services i need to do 50 db calls and again have to do data formatting logic.

Comment: Generally speaking, looping itself isn't very expensive - fetching from the database is. Fetch all your records from the database (single request) and save it in-memory, and loop over that. 1000 iterations is nothing. Besides that, it's not really clear what want to achieve (e.g. there's no input data and expected output)

Comment: ok.. thanks for your suggestion. I will try to do so

Comment: Does the record from the database contain data from multiple tables?

Comment: yes.. currently created a view and fetching data using below query
SELECT * FROM [vw_ServiceDetails]  ORDER BY ServiceId,RouteId,SeqNumber

Answer (score 0):

To avoid looping over the data structure each time, you could build up additional dictionaries that provide fast access of the objects by id:

```
var myServiceIndex = new Dictionary<string, Service>()
var myRouteDataIndex = new Dictionary<string, RouteData>()

Service service;
RouteData routData;

foreach (var record in databaseRecords)
{
    if (myRouteDataIndex.TryGetValue(record.RouteId, out route))
    {
        // add stop data
    }
    else if (myServiceIndex.TryGetValue(record.ServiceId, out service)
    {
        // add route data
        // add stop data 
    }
    else
    {
        // add service
        // add route data
        // add stop data 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of stops, and for each stop entry in database you have to map it to a C# object. In this case, looping is inevitable, as far as I see. Linq, and eg. entity framework, use looping internally.

**One option is to use entity framework or Linq to SQL**. It will give you strong type classes representing each DB table. But you have to change your DB schema and use foreign keys to link service, route, and stops.

C# code would look exactly like yours, which is auto generated by entity framework and in-sync with DB schema.

**Second option is to convert manually**. Note, your current schema doesn't complient with [Third normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form). If you don't want to change your schema, you could read and generate them using `group by` clause.